# How do I find the jpeg header in a compressed image with jpeg

Tags: image, image-processing, header, jpeg

I have five compressed images  and I need to find raw data from these images. That's why I have to find out the Jpeg heading. but the header of each image is different.I think jpeg doesn't have a fixed header like bmp etc.

Comment: What use will the raw data be if you have ignored the header? You won't know the image width and height, nor how to decompress it.

Answer (score 0):

JPEG does not define a header or a file format at all. There are several jpeg file formats in use, notably JFIF, EXIF, SPIFF, and Adobe.

The formats define APPn markers that are expected to appear after the SOI marker. However, most decoders will try to figure the image out without these headers.

You do not need a header to find the image data. You scan the stream for JPEG markers.